# Netlogo: Read-from-string expects literal value

Tags: list, netlogo

The following triggers an "expected literal value" warning, what am I missing?  I would expect the value 1000 to be returned.

```
let item-cost ["dia-cost"]
let item-cost first item-cost
print read-from-string item-cost
```

Comment: Why would you expect 1000? Is "dia-cost" the name of a variable, the value of which is 1000?  You have given read-from-string a string.which it does not know how to parse.

Comment: yes - sorry for missing - dia-cost = 1000, in this example I missed it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in the comments, `dia-cost` is a variable with the value of `1000` that you're looking to get out.  The core of the issue is that [`read-from-string`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#read-from-string) only reads literal values of the type number, list, string, boolean, or nobody.  The wording there is a bit confusing, as it says, "Interprets the given string as if it had been typed in the Command Center", so I could see how it'd seem like a variable should give its value with `read-from-string` just as you'd see in the Command Center, but variables are not literal values of those limited types.

Fortunately there is an easy alternative, you can use [the `runresult` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run) and it will interpret the string as the variable name and get you the value:

```
to test
  let dia-cost 1000
  let item-cost ["dia-cost"]
  set item-cost first item-cost
  show runresult item-cost ; prints "1000"
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - i had totally forgot about runresult primitive